# Javascrypt copy to clipboard function copying just first row

Tags: javascript, php, copy, clipboard

I am a beginner in JavaScript and I do not know how to solve this problem. I have created a table based on my database in MySQL. And now I want to copy one of its cells with the copy button. But my function only copies the first cell. I know I have to give my text different IDs but I do not know how.
Here is my code:

```
             <tr>
                <td class="ttd">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="ttd"><?php echo htmlentities($f['ID']); ?> </td>
                <td class="ttd"><?php echo htmlentities($f['Invoice_number']); ?> </td>
                <td class="ttd"><?php echo htmlentities($f['Invoice_date']); ?> </td>
                <td class="ttd"><?php echo htmlentities($f['Month']); ?> </td>
                <td class="ttd"><?php echo htmlentities($f['Space_name']); ?> </td>
                <td class="ttd"><?php echo htmlentities($f['Company_name']); ?> </td>
                <td class="ttd"><?php echo htmlentities($f['Amount']); ?> </td>
                <div class="tooltip">
                <td class="ttd">
                    <input type="text" style="display:none;" id="Key" value="hhhhhhh.php?token=<?php echo $current_token['token']; ?>">
                    <button onclick="myFunction()" >Copy</button>


                    <script>
                    document.forms[0].addEventListener("submit", function(event){
                            if ( send == 0 ) { event.preventDefault(); }
                            });
    
                    function myFunction() {
                    var hidden = document.getElementById("Key");
                    hidden.style.display = 'block';
                    hidden.select();
                    hidden.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
                    document.execCommand("copy");
                    alert("Copied the text: " + hidden.value);
                    hidden.style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    </script>
                </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Do you need to copy the text of the cells only, or do you also need the table markup to the clipboard?

Comment: Your HTML code is not valid FYI A div is not a child of a TR

Comment: just copy the cell

Comment: thanks epascarello

Comment: If this code is inside of a loop, then you're going to have issues. ID attributes **must** be unique, so you'll need to name them something different. I'd suggest reading up on data attributes, as it might be easier to handle. You can use `Key` as the class, or use an event handler to get the element that's being clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you need remove id property ("key") from your input text, because there should be no duplicate ids on a document.

Then you can change your js, taking the input ("key") element by its sibling to current clicked button.

```js
 function myFunction(el) {
  var hidden = el.previousElementSibling;
  hidden.style.display = 'block';
  hidden.select();
  hidden.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + hidden.value);
  hidden.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ttd">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="ttd">1</td>
    <td class="ttd">2</td>
    <td class="ttd">3</td>
    <td class="ttd">4</td>
    <td class="ttd">5</td>
    <td class="ttd">6</td>
    <td class="ttd">7</td>
    <td class="ttd">
      <input type="text" style="display:none;" value="12321">
      <button onclick="myFunction(this)" >Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ttd">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="ttd">1</td>
    <td class="ttd">2</td>
    <td class="ttd">3</td>
    <td class="ttd">4</td>
    <td class="ttd">5</td>
    <td class="ttd">6</td>
    <td class="ttd">7</td>
    <td class="ttd">
      <input type="text" style="display:none;" value="2222">
      <button onclick="myFunction(this)" >Copy</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using the same id over and over. Ids need to be singular in a document. So either you have to give every input a unique id and unique function names or you change your code to look it up based on the button and make it reusable.

You need to reference the element that is beside it. You can either use siblings or you can look at the td and find the element.

Using event delegation so you are not adding a bunch of click handlers to the document.

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector("#myTable tbody");
tbody.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

  // get clicked button
  const btnCopy = event.target.closest(".copy");
  if (btnCopy) {
    copyThis(btnCopy);
  }

});

function copyThis(button) {
  const hiddenInput1 = button.previousElementSibling;
  console.log(hiddenInput1.value);
  
  const hiddenInput2 = button.closest("td").querySelector('input[type="hidden"]');
  console.log(hiddenInput2.value);
  
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="1">
        <button type="button" class="copy">Copy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="2">
        <button type="button" class="copy">Copy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you really want to use inline events

```js
function copyThis(button) {
  const hiddenInput1 = button.previousElementSibling;
  console.log(hiddenInput1.value);
  
  const hiddenInput2 = button.closest("td").querySelector('input[type="hidden"]');
  console.log(hiddenInput2.value);
  
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="1">
        <button type="button" class="copy" onclick="copyThis(this)">Copy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
      <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="2">
        <button type="button" class="copy" onclick="copyThis(this)">Copy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but my cell is part of loop of my databank. I can't add two or more td with different id for similar value of my data bank. I try to add an ID like id = "<?php echo "key".$ff['ID']; ?> but i don't know how can i ust it

Comment: thak you epascarello, second code, that you wrote, give me in log right value, but i don't know how use it in copy button

Comment: Um, `hiddenInput1` is the same thing as `hidden` in your code. I assumed you would have figured that out. Guess not.